# How to use custom css file when converting page to pdf using EvoPDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, evopdf

I want to use custom, external CSS file when converting my ASP.NET MVC page to pdf using EvoPDF library. I don't see anywhere any Styles property that indicates it could be done, is it possible? Do you know any workaround to have specific CSS styles only for conversion using EvoPdf?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) rule to target only a certain mediatype. You could then set the mediatype of the rendered HTML using EvoPDF:

```
var pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(serverIp, serverPort)
        {
            MediaType = "evopdf"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an automatic process to create a Style.cshtml file which is a partial injected into the default layout.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
fs = require('fs'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
gap = require('gulp-insert');

gulp.task('default', function () {
     return gulp.src("Content/main.scss")
         .pipe(sass())
         .pipe(rename("_style.cshtml"))
         .pipe(gap.wrap("<style>\n", "</style>"))
         .pipe(gap.transform(function (contents, file) {
          // Prevent @Fontface etc from causing errors
          return contents.replace(/@/g, "@@");
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest("Views/Shared/"));
});
```